# Strange tag synonym behavior

Tags: discussion, bug, tag-synonyms, tags

I have seen some strange behavior with tagging this week's parasha.  I started typing

`parashat-s` and was surprised to not see [parashat-shemot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashat-shemot) come up as an auto-complete suggestion.  What I saw was:[image: no shemot option]

So I figured this was one of those cases where we [simply don't have](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2111/1713) the sefaradi pronunciation as a tag synonym, so I went to try to tag it with the "Ashkenazis" version of the tag. The first time, I actually started just typing `shemo` without the introducing `parashas...`, and much to my surprise, I saw this:[image: parashat-shemot is available]

Here, it says that [parashas-shemos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashas-shemos) is available as a tag, but that [parashat-shemot](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashat-shemot) is a synonym of it. So why didn't that suggestion pop up before?  Strangely, if I type `parashas-s` I see [parashas-shemos](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashas-shemos) as a suggestion, but it doesn't mention any tag synonyms. Also, while I see [parashas-shoftim](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashas-shoftim) as a choice, I do not see [parashas-shelach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashas-shelach) or [parashas-shemini](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashas-shemini) which appeared when I typed `parashat-s`:[image: parashas]

So what's going on here?

**EDIT**

[parashas-shelach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashas-shelach) and [parashas-shemini](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashas-shemini) do not exist as tags or as synonyms of [parashat-shelach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashat-shelach) and [parashat-shemini](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parashat-shemini) respectively, so that answers the final question.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Wasn't sure whether to include that tag or not. I guess I'll throw it in for now until it's shown to be something else.

Comment: Related? http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1965/5323 + http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1776/5323

Comment: @Shokhet, looks like it to me.

Comment: Daniel, if you think I'm mistaken that this is a duplicate, please lemme know.

Comment: @msh210, I thought we only dupe nowadays if the other post has an answer.

Comment: @IsaacMoses, I thought even if not as long as it's a clear duplicate. (Which it is to me, but which is kinda why I commented above.) Lemme see if I can find the relevant MSE post....

Comment: ... ["...Moderators can override this last restriction if necessary. The rationale here is that it can be fairly hard to discern whether or not an unanswered question is actually a duplicate..."](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/165933)

Comment: ^ @IsaacMoses ^